# What kind of popover on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller, uiactionsheet, popover

The iPad app pdf expert displays popovers which seem to consist only of the header. Which kind of popover is this? I can't find something about it in the Apple docs. But it seems to be a standard UI element. Or is it a custom view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its nothing like a custom view. Its just without UINavigationController.

```
        ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
        UIPopoverController * popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:viewController];
        popover.delegate = self;
        popover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(644, 425);
        [popover presentPopoverFromRect:button.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft | UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

This will solve you problem. Check it out.!!